passing cache folder to Azure Openai Embeddings
I was working on implementing the Azure Openai Models in my code.
I was able to implement the Azure Openai LLM model which is working fine.
Now I want to have the AzureOpenaiEmbeddings implemented for which I have the code below:
            embedding_model = AzureOpenAIEmbedding({"cache_folder":"data/models"},model="text-embedding-ada-002",
            deployment_name="gpt-35-turbo-v0301",
            api_key=AZURE_API_KEY,
            azure_endpoint=AZURE_ENDPOINT,
            api_version=AZURE_API_VERSION,
            )

Here I'm trying to pass the cache folder so that I can store embeddings in a specific folder but I get an error:
An error occurred: {'cache_folder': 'data/models'} is not a valid OpenAIEmbeddingMode
Is there a way how I can store the embeddings in a specific folder??
I have tried the above steps and encountered the issue.
